# programmatically get the shipping tax by order increment id

Tags: shipping, tax

how can i programmatically get the shipping tax from an order increment_id in magento?

I try this script, but seems not to work.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId("increment_id");
$taxRefunded = $order->getTaxRefunded();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure if you need the shipping tax or shipping cost. Here are both.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId("increment_id");
//shipping cost
$shippingCost = $order->getShippingAmount();
//shipping cost in base currency
$shippingBaseCost = $order->getBaseShippingAmount();
//shipping tax
$shippingTax = $order->getShippingTaxAmount();
//shipping tax in base currenty
$shippingBaseTax = $order->getBaseShippingTaxAmount();
//shipping cost including tax
$shippingCostIncludingTax = $order->getShippingInclTax();
//shipping cost including tax in base currency
$shippingBaseCostIncludingTax = $order->getBaseShippingInclTax();
```